# Python 3.x: Update a project instead of copy entire project each time

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am not sure if this functionality exists. Here is the scenario:

I have used [this](http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project) to setup my project and I run the `$ python setup.py sdist` command each time i want to make a new release. The problem is, this make start to get redundant and the process may take too long, especially when all i have updated is one or 2 files. I don't need to create an entire new project, just update what has changed from the previous one. Is there anyone way to do this? If this is not clear then I can try to explain better, but lets see if people understand what i am getting at.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Anyway distribute which is like easy_install or pip will arrive in Python 3.4 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indeed want to make a release each time and are bothered by the time it takes, you are probably making releases too often.

However, if you're only looking for installing the package locally for testing, you should be doing  `pip install -e /path/to/package`, which creates symlinks for your package in the system. You only need to do this once. Every change to the package source will be immediately seen by the system